# Is it possible to import a Project server 2003 site or site collection to SharePoint 2007 standard edition?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, project-server

Is it possible to migrate a Project server 2003 site or site collection to SharePoint 2007 standard edition?

If not, Why?

If so, How?

I tried with quest migration manager, then renamed web temp files and am getting destination template errors

Answer (score 1):

Sites in a 2003 Project Server likely use a custom SharePoint site definition that doesn't exist in the standard 2007 product.  That's probably why Quest's tool is failing and it is definitely the reason why stsadm backup and then restore will fail.

Even if you tried the content database attach method of of upgrading SharePoint, you will find that it will fail as well because of the missing site definition.

I suppose if you got a hold of the Project Server 2007 site definitions you could maybe make this work in a half hearted way but none of the supporting infrastructure for the site definition would be there and you'd likely be violating Microsoft licensing.